# rgba color does not working as inline css in tcpdf table

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf, rgba

I'm integrating tcpdf for pdf generation. I having problem in background-color not appearing in pdf. I'm using rgba color code for background-color table rows.

**html code:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Mark</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>test</td>
<td style="background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 1) none repeat scroll 0 0">100<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>test2</td>
<td style="background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.85) none repeat scroll 0 0">66<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>test3</td>
<td style="background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.22) none repeat scroll 0 0">45<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>test4</td>
<td style="background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.08) none repeat scroll 0 0">12<td/>
</tr>
</table>
```

**PHP Code**

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(200, '', '50', '40', $html, 0, 1, 1, true, 'C', true);
```

if tcpdf not support rgba code. How to convert rgba into html color code for that corresponding values.Kindly guide me. I'm looking forward for your reply.

Comment: Did you write the `writeHTML(...)` part?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd No, I did $pdf->writeHTMLCell(150, '', '80', '80', $html, 0, 1, 1, true, 'C', true);

Answer (score 0):

`TCPDF` will not support normal `html` `style` property. you  have to add below line to set the bg color.

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(0,255,0);
```

for setting opacity try

```
$pdf->SetAlpha(0.5);
```

`$pdf` is `TCPDF` class object
[reference TCPDF documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_017.phps)

Comment: need to set opacity for the background color that's why i use rgba().